# Formatting a response appropriately with restsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, restsharp

I've got the following classes declared to manage my response back with the help of json2csharp

```
public class Address
{
  public string addressLine1 { get; set; }
  public string addressLine2 { get; set; }
  public string addressLine3 { get; set; }
  public string locality { get; set; }
  public string province { get; set; }
  public string postalCode { get; set; }
  public string country { get; set; }
}

public class Component
{
  public string streetNumber1 { get; set; }
  public string street1 { get; set; }
  public string locality1 { get; set; }
  public string postalCode1 { get; set; }
  public string country1 { get; set; }
  public string countryISO1 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObjectFormat
{
public List<Address> address { get; set; }
public List<Component> components { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my call

```
var client = new RestClient(cmboxOutput.Text); //this has a full url in it for a get response
var formatRequest = new RestRequest();
formatRequest.AddHeader("token", "XYZ");
IRestResponse<RootObjectFormat> formatResponse = client.Execute<RootObjectFormat>(formatRequest);
```

Now I get a response back which is great. But it is nested. Unfortunately the following for each loop gets the data with an incorrect format.

```
 foreach (var result in formatResponse.Data.address)
 {
  rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text + result.addressLine1 + '\n';
  rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text + result.addressLine2 + '\n';
  rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text + result.addressLine3 + '\n';
  rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text + result.locality + '\n';
  rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text + result.postalCode + '\n';
  rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text + result.country + '\n';  
 }
```

Since it is nested to grab addressLine2 I have to wait for the second time the loop is carried out, at the end my output looks very unprofessional. Is there a better way to do this? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzwcD.png < first run on the loop
https://i.stack.imgur.com/24cco.png < fifth run

Found a better way of outputting the format from a response, yet it's still not that perfect. Any way to improve this?

```
 foreach (var result in formatResponse.Data.address)
 {
   rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text +"\n"+   string.Join("",result.addressLine1 + result.addressLine2
                + result.addressLine3 + result.postalCode + result.province + result.country);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var result in formatResponse.Data.address)
        {
            var str = "";
            str = string.Join("",result.addressLine1 + result.addressLine2
                + result.addressLine3 + result.postalCode + result.province + result.country);
            if (str != "")
            {
                rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text = rchtxtbxOutputLayout.Text + str.ToString() + "\n";
            }
```